# Storing random array value with intervals

Tags: javascript

How would I go about replacing the old 'box' with a white/no background?

```
var counter = 11;
var check = 0;
var boxes = ["box_1","box_2","box_3","box_4"];

clock = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter==0) {
        clearInterval(clock);
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Time Left: 0 seconds.";
    } else {
        var box = boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)];
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Time Left: " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
        document.getElementById(box).style.backgroundColor="#000";
    }
}, 1000);
```

I attempted to store the box as `old_box` -> `old_box = box` which didn't work.

**It seems people are misunderstanding. 
I want to store the box value so I can call it back on the next loop and set it to white, while the new box can be set to black.**

Comment: #000 is black not white.
Your title doesn't appear to relate to your question

Comment: @DJL you are misunderstanding. I want the old box to be set to white and the new one set to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the box:

```
var counter = 11;
var check = 0;
var boxes = ["box_1","box_2","box_3","box_4"];
var lastbox = false;
clock = setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if(counter==0) {
    clearInterval(clock);
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Time Left: 0 seconds.";
} else {
    if (lastbox) {
        document.getElementById(lastbox).style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
    }
    lastbox = boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)];
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Time Left: " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    document.getElementById(lastbox).style.backgroundColor="#000";
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You're a Genius, my friend! At least someone understood what was being asked.

Comment: You need to define your **variable** `clock`.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xodox/8/edit)**

Simply set the background to `#000` to the element
which ***index-matches*** the random number `(r==i)`

```
function $id(_) { return document.getElementById(_);   }
function $el(_) { return document.querySelectorAll(_); }
function game() {
  if (!c) clearInterval( clock );
  $cou.innerHTML = "Time Left: "+ (c--) +" seconds.";
  var r = ~~(Math.random()*n);
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) $box[i].style.backgroundColor = i==r?"#000":"#fff";
}

var $box = $el("[id^=box_]"),
    $cou  = $id("counter"),
    n = $box.length,
    c = 10,
    clock = setInterval(game, 1000);
```

As you can see I've also used some nice reusable functions so further in your project you don't need to loose your fingers writing all over the place `document.getElementById` but simply:

```
$id("elementID")
```

or if you want to get more elements using a wide spectrum of selectors: <sub>(slower)</sub>

```
$el(".elements")       // [] array collection
$el("[id^=prefix]")    // [] array collection
$el("input")           // [] array collection
```